# I'm not really sure how to use Twine to upload my project to testpypi

Tags: python, module, pypi, twine

So I tried to use the command `python -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*` and after I press enter, it appears a prompt asking for my username, I tried entering my test pypi username, __ token __, or the name of my token, but non of them works. If I enter anything, press enter, it will just go onto the next line and never does anything.
Am I missing any steps? Or what am I doing wrong? I am following the Pypi docs btw

Comment: Does it prompt for a password?

Comment: nope, it just asks for my username, i entered, it just stop there. @DustinIngram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem by switching to a different terminal. Thanks!